# Force directing a particle in a plane yielding a system of differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose we have some particle of mass $m$ that moves in a plane of coordinates $(x(t), y(t)$ under the influence of a force directed toward the origin with magnitude $$ \frac{k}{x^2 + y^2}$$ I need to show that $$mx^{\prime \prime} = \frac{-kx}{r^3}$$ and $$my^{\prime \prime} = \frac{-ky}{r^3}$$ for $r = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$.

To solve this, I noticed that the force acting on the particle at any given moment is directed along an angle $\theta$ that is equivalent to $\arctan(\frac{y(t)}{x(t)})$. Thus, the force in the $x$ direction (assuming the particle is in the first quadrant) would be $$\frac{-k}{x^2 + y^2} \cos ( \arctan(\frac{y(t)}{x(t)}) )$$ which would yield $$mx^{\prime \prime} = \frac{-k}{x^2 + y^2} \cos ( \arctan(\frac{y(t)}{x(t)}) )$$ which is obviously the wrong answer.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

Let

$
\vec x = \begin{pmatrix}x\\y \end{pmatrix}
$
The force, as a vector is:
$$
\vec F=\frac{k}{|\vec x|^2}\frac{-\vec x}{|\vec x|}=\frac{-k \vec x}{|\vec x|^3}
$$
and $|\vec x|=r$

Comment: Where $\frac{\vec x}{|\vec x|}$ is the unit vector, i.e. the direction of the force $\vec x$?

Comment: Yes it is! Right. So you can easily find the result.

Comment: Sorry. I forgot the minus sign. Edit.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your answer is very close to correct:
$$ \cos(\arctan(x)) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}} $$

Thus (still considering the first quadrant):
$$ \cos(\arctan(\frac{y}{x})) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{y^2}{x^2}}} = \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}$$

Now, having $r = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$, you can deduce the desired result.

Of course, this is a lot less elegant than Emilio's answer, but they do give the same result !

Comment: Thank you for the clarification!